# Rspec not working with having < operator in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, controller, operators

I'm following Ryan Bates railscasts on password reseting. I decided to implement his code through TDD but one of my tests refuses to work. Whenever I run

```
context "for checking update succeeds" do
  before do
    post :update, id: "2012-12-03 04:23:13 UTC"
  end

  it { should assign_to(:user) }      
  it { should respond_with(:redirect) }
  it { should redirect_to(signin_path) }
  it { should set_the_flash.to("Password has been reset.")}

end
```

I get the following error

```
 Failure/Error: post :update, id: "2012-12-03 04:23:13 UTC"
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
```

My controller is as follows

```
def update
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
    redirect_to new_password_reset_path, flash[:error] = "Password reset has expired"
  elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to root_url, flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
  else 
    render :edit
  end
end
```

I have to assume I'm writing my test wrong in some form or fashion. How do I fix this? Note that I'm aware the utc time is off date and based on yesterday's time.

Comment: Seems like `@user.password_reset_sent_at` is `nil`. If it is allowed to be `nil`, you should check by `if @user.password_reset_sent_at && @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago`. If it shouldn't be allowed to, you have a bug somewhere in your model. The test seems fine.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. Now I need to go check the model. Post this as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from comment:

Seems like `@user.password_reset_sent_at` is `nil`. If it is allowed to be `nil`, you should check by

```
if @user.password_reset_sent_at && @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
```

If it shouldn't be allowed to, you have a bug somewhere in your model. The test seems fine.